# Unwanted references in author proof

Tags: publications, proofreading

By mistake, unwanted references are present in my accepted manuscript and I want to remove them from my author proof copy. Will the manuscript go to the editor once again or not?

Answer (score 4):

At the author proof stage, you are expected to not make any more substantive changes.
Thus, if the copyeditors introduced these unwanted references, there is zero problem in asking for them to be removed.

If you realize that you messed up any put in things that you should not have or wish that you had not, however, it's a bit more iffy.  You can ask to have them removed and the journal staff will make a judgement call of whether it requires reconsideration or not.  If it's a simple mistake, don't worry about it.  If you were to try to remove all references to prior work, on the other hand, they would be right to consider that a serious substantive change and to strenuously object.

Bottom line: just explain why you want the references removed, and if it's reasonable don't worry about it.

Comment: the text of the article does not cite those references as they are not needed and the copyeditors have included them as citations which is not needed.

Comment: @Curious Then you are likely on solid ground to object.

Comment: "The copyeditors have included them as citations". How is that possible? The journal editors added new references without your knowledge? Is this really a serious journal?

Comment: there were present in the references and copyeditors have included them and cited them. I do not know what made them do that but I ll surely get it corrected.

Comment: I recently corrected the proofs of one of my papers. The copy editors had found two references in the bibliography that were not cited in the text. (They had been cited in earlier drafts but not in the final one.) They asked me to either insert citations for them in the text or remove them from the bibliography. That seems reasonable to me. I can't imagine why any copy editors would want to insert citations (in random places?) on their own.

Comment: @AndreasBlass (being a copy editor myself) Why? **BECAUSE.** `\end{sarcasm}` Now seriously, mistakes happen. For this reason, it is IMHO good to remove uncited references from your `bib` file if you submit in LaTeX. I actually personally prefer not to submit the `bib` file and just copy-paste the `bbl` file in place of `\bibliography{file}` in the source code; it reduces the chance of bibliography getting messed up. However, some journals (AMS for instance) enforce the `bib` file submitted.

Comment: @yo' I didn't use BibTeX in that paper or (in any of my recent papers).  I agree that it's good, in general, to remove uncited references, and I'm glad the copy editors caught those two.